# Alphabet conversion in php

Tags: php, cpu-word

Is there a way i can change the spanish word which i have typed in the textbox to its english word in php.

Is there any way to do this in php.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean. Best make an example.

Comment: Do you mean translation, character encoding or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) to do conversion. [For example](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Translate):

> ```
> google.language.translate("Hello world", "en", "es", function(result) {
>   if (!result.error) {
>     var container = document.getElementById("translation");
>     container.innerHTML = result.translation;
>   }
> });
> ```

that's Javascript. There is a [PHP port](http://code.google.com/p/php-language-api/).

> ```
> <?php
> /**
> * example usage
> */
>
> // we need the page treated as utf-8, otherwise the encoding will be mangled
> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
>
> // require google language api class
> require_once('google.translator.php');
>
> // translate text
> $text = 'Welcome to my website.';
> $trans_text = Google_Translate_API::translate($text, 'en', 'it');
> if ($trans_text !== false) {
>         echo $trans_text;
> }
> ?>
> ```